# Why does a <h2> inside a <h1> not inherit the value of color property?

Tags: html, css

Look at this simple example:

```
<style>
   h1 {
      color: red;
   }
</style>

<h1>this is the 'h1'.<h2>this is the 'h2'</h2></h1>
```

I expected the color of the string within the 'h2' to be red, but it is still black.

This has confused me for a while. Why does it happen?

Comment: h1 tags should never contain h2 tags ...

Comment: @sunivengg: you have set the color property only to tag h1 not to h2.

Comment: validation fails if you using h2 tag in h1.

Comment: As mentioned by everyone, do not put a heading tag inside another heading tag. Take a look at @kevin-bowersox post below, that is the most informative of all, i think. Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An [`<h1>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html) element is not permitted to contain `<h2>` elements (among others; only [phrasing elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) and text are permitted), so according to the spec that is invalid HTML.

The browser tries to compensate for the invalid HTML by considering that the `<h2>` is actually *outside* the `<h1>`, which leads to the observed result.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at how the markup is rendered you will notice the `h2` tag is rendered outside of the `h1` tag.

Nesting these tags within each other is not proper syntax.

**Rendered Markup**

```
<h1>this is the 'h1'.</h1>
<h2>this is the 'h2'</h2>
```

Try switching the `h2` with a `span` and styling as needed.

**HTML**

```
<h1>this is the 'h1'.<span>this is the 'h2'</span></h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1.span{
   /*desired styling*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have set the color property only to tag h1 not to h2.

To overcome this, you can write class to set the same color for both the tags

```
<style>
   .color1 {
  color: red;
  }
</style>

<h1 class="color1">this is the 'h1'.<h2 class="color1">this is the 'h2'</h2></h1>
```

Comment: Karthik, I'm sorry for contacting you like this, but I didn't know how else to get in touch with you. I noticed you voted to put my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743387/how-to-increment-upvote-total-in-my-view-after-successful-ajax-request-to-upvote on hold. It's been edited to be more clear now, and I badly need an answer soon. Please consider withdrawing your vote, so I can place a bounty on it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [HERE](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=641653)

> HTML 4.01’s DTD, for example, says that H1-H6 are block-level elements
>   with an inline  content model. So for layout purposes, they appear on
>   a new line, but for content purposes,  they shouldn’t contain other
>   block-level elements.