# How to increment upvote total in my view after successful Ajax request to upvote action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Thing` model that has many upvotes via an `UpVote` model. I want to be able to create a new `UpVote` object via Ajax from `things/show` and increment the upvote total without refreshing the page.

Creating a new `UpVote` record via Ajax works, however I cannot increment the upvote count in the view.

How can I increment the upvote totals upon successful creation of an upvote?

Here is what I have tried so far:

---

**views/things/show.html.erb**

```
<div id= "thing">

  <div id="upvote">
    <%= @thing.up_votes.count %>
  </div>

  <div id= "vote">
    <%= link_to "upvotething", upvote_thing_path(@thing.id), :remote => true, :id => "new_upvote_link", method: :post, :class => "btn btn-small" %>
  </div> 

</div>
```

---

**views/things/create.js.erb**

```
$('#new_up_vote').remove();
$('#new_up_vote_link').show();
$('#up_votes').append('<%= j render("up_vote", :up_vote => @up_vote)%>');
```

---

**views/things/upvote.js.erb**

```
alert("here");
$('#up_votes').html('<%= @new_votes_count %>');
```

---

**controllers/things_controller.rb**

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    @thing.up_votes.build
    @up_vote = UpVote.new
  end

  def upvote
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    UpVote.create!(ip: request.remote_ip, voteable_id: params[:id], voteable_type: 'Thing')
    respond_to do |format|
      if @up_vote.save
        @new_votes_count = @thing.up_votes.count
        format.html { redirect_to @thing, notice: 'Voted up' }
        format.json { render json: @up_vote, status: :created, location: @up_vote }
        format.js
      else
        @new_votes_count = @thing.up_votes.count
        format.html { redirect_to @thing, notice: 'Voted up failed' }
        format.json { render json: @up_vote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end

  private

    def thing_params
      params.require(:thing).permit(:name, :avatar, :email)
    end

end
```

---

**models/thing.rb**

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :up_votes, as: :voteable
  # ...
end
```

---

**models/up_vote.rb**

```
class UpVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
end
```

---

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

---

**routes.rb**

```
#...
post 'things/upvote/:id' => 'things#upvote', as: 'upvote_thing'
resources :things do
  resources :up_votes
end
```

---

**application.js head**

```
<head>
  <title>Application</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "jquery-ui.min" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "external/jquery/jquery" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui.min" %>
</head>
```

Comment: `$('#upvote').append(' @up_vote)%>');` <-- Explain that. Why is there half an ERb tag?

Comment: @Substantial I thought it was strange too, but that was the syntax used in the last tutorial I read.

Comment: That's a pretty significant error; missing a whole chunk of code. It looks like a call to a helper method. No wonder it doesn't work. Do you have a link to where you found that?

Comment: @Substantial (http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/ajaxify-your-site-with-remote-true) It seemed to have good feedback.

Comment: The blog post is messed up. Here is the [proper line from the linked source code](https://github.com/mohitjain/ajaxified_scaffold/blob/master/app/views/products/create.js.erb#L5): `$('#products').append('<%= j render("product", :product => @product) %>');`

Comment: @Substantial Ah, that makes way more sense.

Comment: I left a comment for the blog owner. Trust your eye next time. It was right.

Comment: @Substantial Thanks for catching that :)

Comment: If someone could explain to me what exactly is unclear about my question, I would be happy to clarify.

Comment: @Substantial What do you think is unclear about my question, and how do you think I could clarify it?

Comment: I cleaned it up for you and voted to reopen. Examine [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26743387/4). There was too much irrelevant code and the title/body talked about your situation instead of the problem. Downvotes will likely stay as there are several obvious errors in your code. **I do have an answer for you if/when the question reopens.** Ping me again if I don't come back.

Comment: If anyone thinks this question is still too broad, please explain why and I will edit it further.

Comment: @Substantial The question has now been reopened.

Comment: Can you post the snippet from your development.log which shows the Upvote record being created, a 200 (or 201) response, and the upvote.js.erb view being rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the answers worked for me...This is what I ended up doing:

**things/show.hmtl.erb:**

```
<div id="<%= thing.name %>"> <%= thing.up_votes.count %> </div>
<a id="<%= thing.name.downcase %>_link"><%= link_to "upvote", upvote_thing_path(:id => thing.id), remote: true, method: :get %></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#<%= thing.name.downcase %>_link").click(function () {
    $.get( "<%= upvote_thing_path(:id => thing.id) %>", function( data ) {
      $('#<%= thing.name %>').html(data + ' %');
    });
  });
</script>
```

**controllers/things_controller.rb**

```
def upvote
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  UpVote.create!(ip: request.remote_ip, vanishing: false, voteable_id: params[:id], voteable_type: 'Thing')
  redirect_to @thing
  render text: @thing.up_votes.count.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how you should do it.

**views/things/show.html.erb**

```
<div id= "thing">

  <div id="upvote">
    <%= @thing.up_votes.count %>
  </div>

  <div id= "vote">
    <%= link_to "upvotething", upvote_thing_path(@thing.id), :remote => true, :id => "new_upvote_link", method: :post, :class => "btn btn-small" %>
  </div> 

</div>
```

---

**views/things/upvote.js.erb**

```
$('#up_votes').html('<%= @new_votes_count %>');
```

---

**controllers/things_controller.rb**

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def upvote
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    @up_vote = UpVote.new(ip: request.remote_ip, votable: @thing)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @up_vote.save
        @new_votes_count = @thing.up_votes.count
        format.html { redirect_to @thing, notice: 'Voted up' }
        format.json { render json: @up_vote, status: :created, location: @up_vote }
        format.js
      else
        @new_votes_count = @thing.up_votes.count
        format.html { redirect_to @thing, notice: 'Voted up failed' }
        format.json { render json: @up_vote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

Add a comment if you want anything else

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I typed your code exactly as written, and @thing.up_votes.count still doesn't increment.

Comment: can you check your server log if it has any errors, because this seems like a valid solution.

Comment: @mohameddiaa27 No, there are no errors. A new UpVote is created remotely, but thing.up_votes.count is not refreshed.

Comment: try adding `alert("here");` in the `upvote.js.erb` to make sure it succeeds reaching the view (at the top of the file)

Comment: I edited my `upvote.js.erb` to make sure that's exactly what you had in mind, but if so, it did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

#### Make sure you have the following in your `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: I posted it above along with my routes. It countains both jquery and jquery_ujs.

Comment: Do you include `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>` in your application.html ?

Comment: Yes it's included, I posted my application head as well.

Comment: just for the sake of testing modify your respond_to js to `format.js {render :layout=>false}` .

Comment: I did, it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you hare using Jquery, I would just increment it with the

**Update.js.erb**

```
var num = +$('#up_votes').text();
num += 1;
$('#up_votes').text(num);
```

The + before the $  in var num = +$('#up_votes').text(); turns the string into a integer for yout increment.

You can also use the rails increment() command provided by the rails API to do: 
(In your controller)

```
@new_votes_count.increment!(:up_votes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `respond_to :html, :js` to the top of your controller.

```
  def upvote
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    @up_vote = @thing.up_votes.build(ip: request.remote_ip)
    if @up_vote.save
        respond_with @new_votes_count do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @thing, notice: 'Voted up' }
            format.js {
                @new_votes_count = @thing.up_votes.count
            }
        end
    else
        render :show 
    end
  end
```